# What is $\underbrace{2018^{2018^{2018^{\mathstrut^{.^{.^{.^{2018}}}}}}}}_{p\,\text{times}}\pmod p$ where $p$ is an odd prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, tetration, big-numbers

[This recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2644341/201420142014-bmod2011) inspired me to explore values concerning modulo arithmetic of tetrations, and I thus pose the following question.

> Is there a general expression for the value of $$\underbrace{2018^{2018^{2018^{\mathstrut^{.^{.^{.^{2018}}}}}}}}_{p\,\text{times}}\pmod p$$ where $p$ is odd prime?

We can write the tetration as $^p2018\pmod p$ - for details see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration). Wolfram gives these first values: $$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}p&3&5&7&11&13&17&19\\\hline ^p2018\pmod p&1&1&2&5&3&1&6\end{array}$$ Using FLT is out of the question for large $p$.

---

**EDIT:** Revisiting this question again, I have spotted a pattern in the table.

> **Claim**
>
> Let $q$ be the remainder of $\frac{{}^p2018}p$. Then $$\begin{align}p\equiv\left\{\begin{matrix}
> 0&\quad\text{if}\quad{}q=1\\ 
> 1&\quad\text{otherwise}
> \end{matrix}\right.\pmod{q}\end{align}$$

As @didgogns has mentioned below, all known Fermat numbers satisfy the equality that $${}^p2018\pmod p=1$$

Comment: I feel you are trying to find laws where there are none. Why not inquire for what primes you get an integer whose digits are in a predetermined order?. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito Two months later, I have found a pattern from the table. Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: For all $m \ge 3$, $^m 2018 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$. Can you explain how your claim is true for $p=3$, $q=7$?

Comment: For Claim 2, remind that there are only 5 known Fermat primes and all of them satisfy $a^{65536}\equiv 1 \pmod p$. It is easy to see that $^{p-1}2018$ is multiple of $65536$. Therefore ${}^p2018\equiv (2018^{65536})^{\text{large number}}\equiv1\pmod p$

Comment: There are no primes of form $2^n+1$ except the Fermat primes :)

Comment: What do you mean by "the value of ... mod p"? Do you mean the remainder?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Okay. I think that's a bit of a confusing way to express it - maybe explaining it with remainders or the modulo operation would be clearer.

Comment: Just a thought but what if you factored $2018$ into $2\cdot1009$ and then expanded $^p 2018$ out into a tree of $2$'s and $1009$'s. For instance, $^3 2018 = (2^{(2^{(2\cdot1009)})})^{1009^{(2\cdot1009)}}\cdot(1009^{(1009^{(1009\cdot2)})})^{2^{(1009\cdot2)}}$. Maybe this could lead somewhere?

Comment: Maybe you could also use the series expansion for tetration given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html) and compare it to a series like $\sum p^n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, your claim is not true. I'll prove that$$^{31} 2018 \equiv 28\pmod {31}$$
. Firstly, note that for all $n \geq 2$, $^n 2018$ is multiple of $4$. By Fermat's Little Theorem, we get $^{(n+1)}2018=2018^{^n 2018}\equiv2018^2\equiv1\pmod 3$ and $^{(n+1)}2018\equiv2018^4\equiv1\pmod 5$. It also holds for $n=29$, so $^{30} 2018 \equiv 0 \pmod2$, $^{30} 2018 \equiv 1 \pmod3$ and $^{30} 2018 \equiv 1 \pmod5$. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, $^{30} 2018 \equiv 16 \pmod{30}$.

Now, $^{31} 2018 = 2018^{^{30} 2018} \equiv 2018^{16} \equiv 28\pmod {31}$.

Comment: (+1) Nice! I have found something really interesting about this modulo $31$: the value of ${}^k2018\pmod{31}$ is $28$ for all $k>3$ but neither $2018^{19}\pmod{31}$ nor $19^{2018}\pmod{31}$ equal $28$...

Comment: Note that ${}^32018\pmod{31}=19$